# Requiring Skip and Take When Querying DbSet (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, entity-framework-6

I am experimenting and I am trying to require `Skip()` and `Take()` for every `DbSet` query.

For example, if I try to do this:

```cs
var result = _context.Employee.Include(x => x.Person).ToList();
```

I get a compile time error like Missing `Skip()` or `Take()` value.

Edit: One hurdle that I am facing is needing an `IQueryable` in order to call `Skip()` and `Take()`. If I was able to use those on a `DbSet`, then I would only have to modify the `Context` constructor.

Any other suggestions for automatically reducing the number of records are welcomed.

Comment: Sounds like you want a roslyn analyser. Otherwise I would suggest hiding your context and db sets in private variables, and only access them through methods with take / skip arguments.

Comment: Is this EF 6? That will be relevant if you wanted to say apply default limits.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman those are some awesome suggestions. In regard to the last statement, skip and take require an Iqueryable, so I would have to address that issue

Comment: @AluanHaddad you would be correct.

Comment: The closest you'll be able to come is perhaps applying some maximum number of results. You could go the analyzer route, but it's very different to call these in different contexts such as before or after a where clause. And if you require calling them before materializing with tolist or whatever, how will you know that I haven't already called take?

Comment: I mean you could build an interface like `IQueryable<R,T> Foo(Func<DbSet<R>,IQueryable<T>> init, int skip, int take)` as the only way to get a `DbSet<R>`.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman true, but what if I need to compose on the result. You wouldn't want to encourage people to write every query as a single expression in all cases. Composition is important.

Comment: With that interface you can build any base query & add anything afterwards. You're just forced to have a skip / take in the middle.

Comment: That's true. I thought the point was to ensure `Take`/`Skip` before a materializating operation like `ToList` but your function could perhaps handle that by wrapper the query provider.

Answer (score 0):

You should think by yourself: why do I want to add Skip(...).Take(...)

**I don't want anyone to ask for one million Customers!**

It could be that you want to prevent that a user (= software, not an operator) will query all 10 million Customers:

```
var customers = repository.Customers.Skip(0).Take(Int2.MaxValue);
```

The problem is, that as long as you give users access to your original DbContext, you can't forbid them to do this.

Even if you write your own `ToList(...)`, which adds a Skip / Take, you can't prevent them to use the original `ToList`, or to use `foreach`, or even at its lowest level use `GetEnumerator / MoveNext`.

If you want to make this full proof you'll have to create your own Repository class, which hides the DbContext. If they ask for the `IDbSet<...>` you don't give them the DbSet from the DbContext, but your own object that holds the DbSet of the DbContext.

If users ask this DbSet for `IQueryable<...>`, you don't give it the IQueryable of the DbContext, but your own one.

When users start enumerating this IQueryable, you add Skip / Take

Besides all this, you'll have to do the IQueryable stuff, you also have to write the items to Add / Remove / Update elements.

That's quite a lot of work, and the problem is: it is hardly full proof. Malicious users can still invent queries where your added Skip / Take does not prevent that too many items are fetched.

For instance, if you want to prevent that users ask for more than 1000 Customers at a time, then malicious users can still make groups of users, where every group has 1000 customers. Add Skip(0).Take(1000), and he still gets his one million Customers.

So I don't think that you can do this full proof easily, while still giving users access to all possibilities of a DbSet.

**I want to encourage people to fetch items in limited quantities**

This requirement is a little less demanding, but a lot easier to implement. Encourage the user the possibility to ask the data "per page".

You create a PageCollection, where every Page has a number of items. If the user asks for Page[4], he gets the page where Skip / Take is added to the query.

To make an object of this collection class, the query doesn't have to be executed. Even if you fetch the page, the query doesn't have to be executed. Only when you ask for the elements on the page the query with the added Skip / Take is executed.

How about this:

```
interface IPage<TResult> : IReadOnlyCollection<TResult>
{
    int PageCount {get;}
    int PageNr {get;}
    int PageSize {get;}
}

internal class Page<TResult> : IPage<TResult>
{
    internal IQueryable<TResult> Query {get; internal set;}
    public int PageCount {get; internal set;}
    public int PageNr {get; internal set; }
    public int PageSize {get; internal set;}

    // Implementation IReadOnlyCollection<TResult>
    public int Count => this.PageSize;
    public IEnumerator<TResult> GetEnumerator()
    {
         return this.Query.GetEnumerator();
    }
    
    IEnumerator IEnumerator.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

If you do it like this, then creating the page does not execute the query. It is executed if you start enumerating the items on the page. So fetching a page isn't expensive.

If you think that a fetched page will almost always be enumerated fully, consider to execute the query when the Page is created and save the data in a List. This way you can implement `IReadOnlyList<TResult>` fairly easily. Disadvantage: every time `Page[4]` is created the query is executed, even if no one asks for the elements in the page.

```
private class PageCollection<TResult> : IReadOnlyList<TResult>
{
    private readonly IQueryable<Query> query;
    private readonly int pageSize;
    private readonly int pageCount;

    public PageCollection(IQueryable<TResult> query, int pageSize)
    {
        this.query = query;
        this.pageSize = pageSize;
        int totalCount = query.Count();
        this.pageCount = totalCount / pageSize;
    }

    public int PageSize => this.pageSize;
    public int PageCount => this.pageCount;
    public IPage<TResult> GetPage(int pageNr)
    {
        if (pageNr >= this.PageCount)
        {
             return null; // consider to return empty page
        }

        return new Page<TResult>
        {
            PageCount = this.PageCount,
            PageNr = this.PageNr,
            PageSize = this.PageSize,

            Query = this.Query.Skip(this.PageSize * pageNr).Take(this.PageSize),
        }
    }
}
```

Implement IReadOnlyList and IReadOnlyCollection through PageCount and GetPage

Note: to calculate the number of pages I needed to fetch `Count()`. This is a fairly cheap operation, which won't be executed often.

If you really don't want any execution at all, consider to implement `IReadOnlyCollection<TResult>` instead of `IReadOnlyList<TResult>`. Disadvantage: you can't ask: "give me page [4]"

To create the PageCollection, you need to extend `IQueryable<TResult>` with a method that returns a page collection, without executing the query. If you are not familiar with extension methods See [extension methods demystified](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2013/03/08/c.net-little-wonders-extension-methods-demystified.aspx)

```
public IReadOnlyList<IPage<TResult>> ToPageCollection<TResult>(
    this IQueryable<TResult> query,
    int pageSize)
{
    // TODO: decide what to do if query == null. Exception? return empty collection?
    // TODO: what if pageSize <= 0? What if PageSize is too large?

    return new PageCollection<TResult>(query, pageSize);
}
```

Usage:

```
int pageSize = this.DataGridView.GetVisibleRows.Count;
var oldCustomerPages = dbContext.Customers
    .Where(customer => customer.Birthday.Year <= 1980)
    .ToPageCollection(pageSize);
```

Note: only `query.Count()` has been executed! This is much faster than fetching the Customers.

```
int pageNrToShow = Int32.Parse(this.textBoxPageNr.Text);
var pageToShow = oldCustomerPages[pageNrToShow];
```

Still the data has not been fetched!

```
foreach (var customer in pageToShow)
{
    ...
}
```

This will finally execute the query.

Fetching the next and the previous page is inexpensive, because it won't execute a query.

```
var pageCollection = ...
IPage<Customer> currentPage;

IPage<Customer> NextPage => pageCollection[currentPage.PageNr+1];
IPage<Customer> PreviousPage => pageCollection[currentPage.PageNr-1];
```